# Do the effects of relics like the Vault Hunter's Relic stack in co-op?

Tags: borderlands-2

[image: Vault Hunter's Relic]

Do the effects of [relics](http://www.bl2wiki.com/Relics) like the Vault Hunter's Relic, stack in co-op?

The effect of the Vault Hunter's Relic is *+5% chance of enemies dropping rare loot*. Will this +5% chance increase if more than one player in co-op mode equips the Vault Hunter's Relic? If yes, how does it increase relative to the number of players?

Also, do the other [similar relics](http://www.bl2wiki.com/Relics) behave in the same way? e.g. What about *Moxxi's Endowment* (Increase XP gained by killing enemies)?

Comment: AFAIK, only relics or class mods that affect the whole party would be capable of effect stacking (this one is not one of them). I'd imagine this percentage is applied only if you were the one to get the kill.

Comment: "*I'd imagine this percentage is applied only if you were the one to get the kill.*" Does the item drop depend which player gets the kill? I made [another question about that here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/86967/4797).

Comment: I could be completely wrong about how it works so take my comment with a grain of salt. The way I see it is that it doesn't affect the party since it doesn't explicitly say so and only works per individual. I think a more appropriate question that needs to be answered first is, "Does relics or class mods that doesn't mention that it affects the whole party do so?"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the effect stacks, but unfortunately the Vault Hunter's Relic is a bit vague about what it does. It doesn't actually increase the spawns of things like E-tech, purple or orange items. Rather, it [decreases the drop rate of white weaponry while slightly increasing the drop rate of green and blue weaponry](https://web.archive.org/web/20190420040705/https://forums.somethingawful.com/showthread.php?threadid=3504490&pagenumber=133&perpage=40):

> So I just investigated the Vault Hunter Relic data.
>
> It modifies two attributes:
>
> GD_Balance.Weighting.GearDrops_RareWeightModifier: +0.05
>   GD_Balance.Weighting.GearDrops_CommonWeightModifier: -0.06
>
> [Let's set them to +100.00 and -100.00!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6jIf.jpg)
>   [image]
>
> Net result: I have not seen a single white weapon drop, greens drop,
>   seen a few blues. Nothing else.
>
> So, what I can gauge from this, is that it shifts a 5% of your chance
>   for whites into non-whites. Doesn't touch anything else. Very low
>   impact, perhaps bordering on useless.

Thus, even with all four players using it, you wouldn't be guaranteed to find any more very rare weaponry than you would normally.

Moxxi's Endowment on the other hand only increases the XP *you* get on enemy deaths, not the XP everyone gets. If all four people had it equipped, they'd each get their own XP increase (say, +5%) as opposed to a stacked increase (in this case, +20% XP per player).

In short, the Vault Hunter's Relic stacks but is sadly kind of useless and you'd be better off equipping something else. Moxxi's Endowment won't stack but it's still useful for grinding levels. In my opinion, equipping a health increase or an action skill cooldown relic would be better than both of them.

Also, you asked if other relics stacked. If you were asking about things like health or shield or resistance boosts, then no, none of those stack with other players. They affect only you.

Comment: Based on the link on your answer, it seems that the *RareWeightModifier* is set to be *+5%*, while the *CommonWeightModifier* is set to be *-6%* by the Vault Hunter's Relic. How does this stack on co-op? At 4 players, will the *RareWeightModifier* be *+20%*, and the *CommonWeightModifier* be at *-24%*?

Comment: Well crap. I guess it's time to stop using that useless relic then.

Comment: @galacticninja The vault hunter's relic doesn't set those values to +5% and -6%, it adds and subtracts from them, thus if all four players are adding and subtracting from the same two values it would indeed stack.

Comment: @Feeble That was what I meant with *set to be +5% and -16%* (add and subtract, respectively) =) So is my computation of the *WeightModifier* values correct in my first comment?

Comment: It should be, yes.

Comment: Is there anywhere else the content from the SA link is posted? Like on a BL2 wiki or someplace? If you're not a registered member SA will shut down read access from time-to-time.

Comment: @Feeble You need to have a somethingawful.com account (which is not free) if you want to access the page in your link. Also, the Google Cache link does not lead to the proper post anymore. Could you quote the relevant parts of that page for those of us unable to access it?

Answer (score -1):

the effect is that I find less bad weapons such as level 48-49 almost all of the drops that I find are level 50 and I find that I get a greater chance to drop legendaries i.e. kill hyperius and get 1 in 10 chance of getting a legendary weapon such as the hornet or the shreddifier