# In co-op, does enemy item/loot drop depend on who gets the kill?

Tags: borderlands-2

[It has been speculated](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/86901/do-the-effects-of-relics-like-the-vault-hunters-relic-stack-in-co-op#comment119975_86901) in [this question of mine](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/86901/do-the-effects-of-relics-like-the-vault-hunters-relic-stack-in-co-op) that the Vault Hunter's Relic's bonus effects are applied only if the player who has it equipped is the one to get the kill.

This leads me to thinking: Does enemy item or loot drop depend on which player gets the kill?

(Note: I'm not asking about the Vault Hunter's Relic *only*, but about game items or other game mechanics that could possibly affect this, in general. I just mentioned the Vault Hunter's relic as an example.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do the effects of relics like the Vault Hunter's Relic, stack in co-op?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/86901/do-the-effects-of-relics-like-the-vault-hunters-relic-stack-in-co-op)

Comment: @OrigamiRobot I don't think so (I asked that question too). I asked [that question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/86901/do-the-effects-of-relics-like-the-vault-hunters-relic-stack-in-co-op) to know if relic effects stack in co-op. This question is not about that.

Comment: Details on how the relic works will include how drops work.  I just think we only need one question about MF in BL2.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot That assumes that only relics affect item drops. I'm asking here if there is *any* game mechanic that could possibly affect an item drop based on which player gets the kill. I'm not asking about relics *only*. I just mentioned the Vault Hunter's Relic as an example.

Comment: The important thing is we only need one question about how drops work in BL2.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot That [other question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/86901/do-the-effects-of-relics-like-the-vault-hunters-relic-stack-in-co-op) is about *relic effects stacking in co-op*, it's not about item drops at all (I know, because I asked that question too). It just so happens that the relic I mentioned there as an example has an 'item drop' effect. I don't think this question is an 'exact duplicate' (your close vote reason) of that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the player who kills it is unimportant. The relic affects global drop values so in theory even enemies not touched by the player (E.g. thresher's killing varkids in the caustic caverns) should have a slightly better drop chances. It is also worth noting that the Vault Hunter's relic only increases the spawn rate of greens and blues while decreasing the spawn rates of white items and even then, the change is miniscule. The relic is also unfortunately the only thing in game that can change these values (at the moment, anyway. Future DLC may change that). You really are better off equipping something else.

Comment: Also worth noting that the Relic's only effect is a slight increase in loot rarity distribution towards non-white quality items.

Comment: Yeah, I should've added that in there as well. Not like I haven't been saying that enough 'round these parts to begin with.

Comment: You can totally edit it in - you always have the ability to edit your own answers. :)

Comment: @Feeble My question is not about the Vault Hunter's Relic *only* (it seems that your answer is directed only at that), but about game items or other game mechanics that could possibly affect this, in general. I just mentioned the Vault Hunter's relic as an example.

Comment: @galacticninja The only item or effect that modifies drop rates is the Relic, so it's the only relevant criteria to discuss.

Comment: @RilgonArcsinh "*The only item or effect that modifies drop rates is the Relic...*" How sure are you of that? And even if that has been verified, then it should be mentioned as part of the answer, and not assumed that the question asker already knows this.

Comment: @galacticninja Given that the game files have been fairly thoroughly deconstructed at this point and the only item that references the tables that the Relic does is the Relic...

Comment: @RilgonArcsinh I didn't know that. If I did, that would affect how I worded my question. It should have been mentioned as part of the answer.

Comment: Well now it is. So stop complaining.

Comment: @Feeble "*So stop complaining.*" I have the right to "complain" since I'm the question asker, clarifying my question. Also, most of my comments above were replies to RilgonArcsinh.