# Does Moxii's Endowment effect exp from other players kills?

Tags: borderlands-2

I am leveling up my low level with my friend. I decided to use the XP relic so I would get more, but now I am wondering if it affects XP from team kills or only my kills.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only *you* are affected by Moxxi's Endowment. The other players in your team are not affected by it (unless they also have Moxxi's Endowment equipped).

<sup>Note: This seems to be corroborated by [Feeble's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/86933/4797) at the related question, ["Do the effects of relics like the Vault Hunter's Relic stack in co-op?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/86901/4797)"</sup>
Also, related, from [an answer by Mufasa](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/85071/4797) at [How does experience work in co-op?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/84869/4797):

> Each player gets the same experience. It is not split between them (like credits), but everyone gets the same amount (like ammo).

So, if you're the only one that has Moxxi's Endowment equipped, then you're the only one that's going to get bonus XP, even from team kills.